# Parse Facebook Dialog Delegate methods not being called

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-ios-sdk, parse-platform

I'm using the Parse SDK to implement a Facebook `apprequests` dialog in my app. For all intents and purposes it just wraps the Facebook SDK, prefixing Facebook methods with `PF_`.

I use this code to prepare and raise the dialog:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I just challenged you to a game!"], @"message",
 [friendIds componentsJoinedByString:@"," ], @"to",
 nil];

PF_FBSession *session = [PFFacebookUtils session];
PF_Facebook *facebook = [[PF_Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:session.appID andDelegate:nil];

facebook.accessToken = session.accessToken;
facebook.expirationDate = session.expirationDate;

[facebook dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

This works well, I'm getting the dialog, I'm able to invite friends to play with the app.

The problem is that the delegate methods are not being called, even though I've set the view controller as a `PF_FBDialogDelegate`:

```
@interface ChallengeFriendsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, PF_FBDialogDelegate> {
    NSArray *facebookFriends;
    NSMutableArray *selectedFriends;
}
```

These are some of the delegate methods I'm talking about:

```
- (void)dialog:(PF_FBDialog *)dialog didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error in Dialog: %@", error);
}

- (void)dialogDidNotCompleteWithUrl:(NSURL *)url {
    NSLog(@"Failure on Facebook server side");
}

- (void)dialogCompleteWithUrl:(NSURL *)url {
    NSLog(@"Did complete with URL");
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
}

- (void)dialogDidNotComplete:(PF_FBDialog *)dialog {
    NSLog(@"Cancelled");
    [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

Without these methods being called I'm really not able to handle the sharing in an intuitive way. I'm stumped as to why they wouldn't be called and feel I've tried everything. Any pointers to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: have you checked whether the control is returning to application ? through the function in application delegate **- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation**

Comment: also check whether sharing to facebook calls the delegate methods, let me know the results.

Comment: just only put the message in params, remove the friends ids , now check,you will see a dialog being opened for adding friends.. after the dialog closes the control must return to you app as i said before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got around the problem by using the `facebook` instance provided by `PFFacebookUtils`. This is deprecated but appears to be the only way to make it call the correct delegate methods at the moment.

Replaced:

```
PF_Facebook *facebook = [[PF_Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:session.appID andDelegate:nil];
```

With:

```
PF_Facebook *facebook = [PFFacebookUtils facebook];
```

Thanks to JP and Aromal for your input.

Comment: I am confused, could you clarify whether or not my suggestion failed?

Comment: how do you get around the fact that this method seems to require the user to login twice?

Answer (score 3):

In your code you have

```
PF_Facebook *facebook = [[PF_Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:session.appID andDelegate:nil];
```

Since you set a nil delegate, I would expect the delegate methods are never called, as you describe.

Could you change this to

```
PF_Facebook *facebook = [[PF_Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:session.appID andDelegate:self];
```

That is assuming that you put the delegate methods in the same class.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but I already tried it before. You're right that it should be instantiated with a delegate but that delegate should probably be the Parse appDelegate rather than self, so that the likes of the handleURL callbacks get called.

Comment: By the by, I awarded you the bounty for the help as it did help me reach the final answer.